# Hybris platform upgrade to version 2005 (NotificationService, NotificationEvent)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris version 2005, `com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.notificationarea.NotificationService` seems to be deprecated
https://help.sap.com/doc/a6c03b79dbfa4fc485848de0711cc149/2005/en-US/backofficeframework/com/hybris/backoffice/widgets/notificationarea/DefaultNotificationService.html

They are suggesting using `com.hybris.cockpitng.util.notifications.NotificationService` instead
https://help.sap.com/doc/a6c03b79dbfa4fc485848de0711cc149/2005/en-US/backofficeframework/com/hybris/cockpitng/util/notifications/NotificationService.html

But from what I can see from the OOTB code `com.hybris.cockpitng.util.notifications.NotificationService` is just extending from the old one `com.hybris.backoffice.widgets.notificationarea.NotificationService` which is deprecated and there are no new methods introduced,

[image]

so even when using this new `NotificationService`, when I call `notificationService#notifyUser` i still get a warning saying that the method `notifyUser` is deprecated.

Is this normal, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If it is what SAP is recommending, it should be fine. SAP will probably update it in the future. There is no problem using deprecated methods, as long as they are still available. However, you might want to update in the future, in case there are major improvements in the new replacements, versus the old one.